# How to check if the value of a DataGridViewCalendarColumn has been changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview, cells

I have a data grid with a calendar column. What I want to do is an event (not sure which one is suitable), and this is what should happen:

1. There should be a check to see if one of the row's dates were changed;
2. If the value of **one** row has been changed (specifically the date column - which is also the only editable column), another method will execute (let's call it `Update()`) - I already have the method figured out. I just don't know how to do the whole check to see if a value has been changed.

`CellValueChanged` doesn't work as it is triggered if anything changed on the grid, such as loading the data etc. Is there something else I can use?

Let me know if I need to add more info, I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
        if (column.Name == "dateColumn")
        {
            UpdateStuff();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateStuff()
    {
        object myDate = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value;
    }
```

Comment: It seems that the `CellValueChanged` event isn't going to work. As soon as I run the application, I get an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error. The event should only be triggered when a value is changed by the user on the column, not when the data loads, or anything like that?

Comment: I guess It's because the InitializeComponent. Which part you get this exception? You can simply add a check before, let's say:
if (!Visible) return;
That way it will do stuff only when the form is visible or finished loading.

Comment: I posted my code. The `CellEndEdit` worked pretty well. You're code helped me get to it, thanks man @Gilad.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void dgvResults_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedColumn = this.dgvResults.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
        var vm = (PurchaseOrdersTrackingViewModel) this.dgvResults.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;

        if (selectedColumn.Name == this.colDueDate.Name)
        {
            this.SingleDueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(this.dgvResults.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[this.colDueDate.Index].Value);

            if (!this._mapicsWorkday.IsWorkDay(this.SingleDueDate.Date))
            {
                this.ShowMessage("Due date selected must be a valid working day.");
                return;
            }
            if (this.SingleDueDate.Date < DateTime.Today)
            {
                this.ShowMessage("You cannot set a past date as a due date.");
                return;
            }

            vm.HasCommentUpdateApplied = true;
            this.UpdateSingleOrder = true;
            this._presenter.BulkUpdateItems();
        }
    }
```